# how to install ejabberd on amazon ec2 using ssh

Tags: ejabberd

I am trying to install ejabberd on Amazon ec2 dedicated server. The machine is Amazon Linux AMI 2014.09.2 (HVM). Can anyone help me regarding this thing.

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd installation is fully documented on ejabberd documentation site: [ejabberd installation](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/).

The easiest approach is to download binary installer from official ejabberd download page, to make it executable on you Linux server and to run the installer executable. For example:

```
chmod +x ejabberd-15.07-linux-x86_64-installer.run
./ejabberd-15.07-linux-x86_64-installer.run
```

There is nothing Amazon EC2 specific.